# RxAndroid to handle the switch case in observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

My android application has to use socket service to handle different command and response  in asychronized way because the commands need to call into other component in application and wait for asychronized result.

I tried to use rxjava to map the incoming string into different parameter but still has to manually route different commmand, is there any operator to route the logic to customized observable and handle the result in the single subscriber ?

The code is following:

```
          Observable.just(command_string)
            .map(new Func1<String, Command>() {
                @Override
                public Command call(String command_string) {
                    ......;
                }
            })
            .filter(new Func1<Command, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Command file) {
                    ThreadUtils.logThreadSignature(TAG);
                    return  !isExcuetingCmd;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Func1<Command, CmdResponse>() {
                @Override
                public CmdResponse call(Command command) {
                    //stupid code...
                    switch (cmd)
                    {
                        case CMD_1:

                            ...
                            CmdResponse = xxx
                            break;

                        case CMD_2:
                            ...
                            CmdResponse = xxx
                            break;

                        case CMD_3:
                            ...
                            CmdResponse = xxx
                            break;                       
                    }
                    return CmdResponse;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<CmdResponse, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(CmdResponse cmdResponse) {
                    return Observable.just(gson.toJson(CmdResponse));
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you can do is use **groupBy** operator, so then depending on your cmdResponse you can add that observable into a group. Then finally when the observable finish to emit, you can check the groups on the subscriber.

The official documentation here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html

Check this example that I did

```
 /**
 * In this example we create a String/Person group.
 * The key of the group is just the String value of the sex of the item.
 */
@Test
public void testGroupBySex() {
    Observable.just(getPersons())
              .flatMap(listOfPersons -> Observable.from(listOfPersons)
                                                  .groupBy(person -> person.sex))
              .subscribe(booleanPersonGroupedObservable -> {
                  switch (booleanPersonGroupedObservable.getKey()) {
                      case "male": {
                          booleanPersonGroupedObservable.asObservable()
                                                        .subscribe(person -> System.out.println("Here the male:" + person.name));
                          break;
                      }
                      case "female": {
                          booleanPersonGroupedObservable.asObservable()
                                                        .subscribe(person -> System.out.println("Here the female:" + person.name));
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              });
}

private List<Person> getPersons() {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Person("Pablo", 34, "male"));
    people.add(new Person("Paula", 35, "female"));
    return people;
}
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Is there a way to customize booleanPersonGroupedObservable to replace switch case so that the code can be more scalable, and actually i expect the final result will be emited as single type and all the code to handle  different request will be the separate class so that subscriber just report the final result to user..

Comment: Without all the details of you requirements I cannot tell, read the documentation that I paste and check if adjust to your needs